# firefox and fontface htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, font-face

To make font-face work on FF I need to make a .htaccess file, upload it to the root directory and that should be it right?

so in a blank text file i write:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I save it, I upload it to the site root and rename it to .htaccess 
but it is not working, no matter what I do.. 
The strangest thing is that ff loads the fonts on some of the pages but not on all

Is there something else that should be added to the text/htaccess file?

Comment: I don't think you should be adding anything else... Perhaps it is a cache issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using htaccess as mentioned above did not solve anything, it actually just made things worse.
The solution was to make all paths relative.

I mean, EVERY path related to the fonts.